# How to arrange the firebase retrieval in an array?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve and display past payments of a user. For this I have used a Recycler-view which takes information from array and displays all the past transactions.

[image]

From above database (in image),I want to retrieve this data and store it in an array in this format:

```
amount[]={"100","200"};             
rid[]={"123456",123456"};             
date_time[]={"16 Aug 2019 14:10:26","16 Aug 2019 14:12:26"};
```

**Below is the code for Android studio where I want the help :**

```
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("payments").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //How to retrieve the data in above array format
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List`:

```
List<String> amountList   = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> ridList      = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> dateTimeList = new ArrayList<>();     
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("payments").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String amount    = ds.child("amount").getValue(String.class);
        String rid       = ds.child("rid").getValue(String.class);
        String dateTime  = ds.child("date_time").getValue(String.class);
        amountList.add(amount);
        ridList.add(rid);
        dateTimeList.add(dateTime);
     }             
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  });
```

Your `databaseReference` is at node `uid` then you loop inside the `uid` and get the value of each attribute, then you can add them inside a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = (int) datasnapshot.getChildrenCount();
String amount[]=new String[count];             
....
// initialize other arrays

int i=0; //loop counter
for(Datasnapshot post: datasnapshot.getChildren){
 ...
 //iterate every value and insert into respective array
}
```

I don't see any way in single Firebase query, apart from this or you can use List<> instead.